# pass data to phtml for custom email template

Tags: email, email-templates, phtml

I am customizing my email by writing a block in template file,

**in email template**

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/external/customer.phtml'}}
```

and **template/email/external/customer.phtml** is

```
$fieldsName = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFields();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsFields();

$message = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessage();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsMessage();
$emailTemplateData = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getEmailTemplateData();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsEmailTemplateData();
?>
<p style="padding: 5px;"><?php echo $message; ?></p>
<?php if ($emailTemplateData) : ?>
    <table style="width:75%; padding: 5px;">
        <tr style="padding: 5px;">
            <td> <strong><?php echo "Field"; ?></strong></td>
            <td> <strong><?php echo "Data"; ?></strong></td>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($emailTemplateData as $key => $value): ?>

            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $fieldsName[$key] . ":"; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $value; ?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </table>

<?php endif; ?>
```

and email is being send like

```
public function sendEmail($subject, $fieldsName, $message, $emailTemplateData) {
        //Want to send these not this way
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setFields($fieldsName);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMessage($message);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEmailTemplateData($emailTemplateData);

        $emailTemplateVariables = array();
        $emailTemplateCode = "External Customer Creation"; //Email Template Code
        $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode($emailTemplateCode);
        $emailSubject = $subject; //Email Subject
        $emailTemplateVariables['templateMessage'] = ""; //Variables for Confirmation Mail. 

        $senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'); //Getting the Store E-Mail Sender Name.
        $senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'); //Getting the Store General E-Mail.
        //Appending the Custom Variables to Template.

        $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

        //Sending email to listed id under 
        //"Admin >> System >> Configuration >> Customer >> Customer Configuration >> External Source Customer Creation >> Confirmation email recipients"
        $emailIds = Mage::getStoreConfig('customer/external_source_customer/confirmation_email_to');
        $toEmailList = explode(",", $emailIds);

        foreach ($toEmailList as $toEmail) {

            $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
                    ->setToName($toName)
                    ->setToEmail($toEmail)
                    ->setBody($processedTemplate)
                    ->setSubject($emailSubject)
                    ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
                    ->setFromName($senderName)
                    ->setType('html');

            try {
                $mail->send();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
    }
```

And my email template is like...

```
<style>
ul {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 14px;
}
</style>

<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
        <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;font-size:12px;">
            <!-- [ header starts here] -->
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2' valign="top"><a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{skin url="images/abc-logo-225x83.png" _area="frontend" _package="default" _theme="abc"}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" colspan='2'>
                    <p style="line-height:16px; margin:0;">
                     {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' mydata=$fieldsName template='email/external/customer.phtml'}}
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2' bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you, <strong>abc Team</strong></p></center></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

This is working fine. But this not a good way, as you can see I am passing data to session to get in my phtml file, what I want is that is there a way pass this data to phtml file in a proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your block write like this and

`{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' mydata="1" template='email/external/customer.phtml'}}`

Your phtml you get this data like this

`echo $this->mydata;`

please check and let me know it help you or not.

Comment: didn't get you, you mean {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' mydata=$fieldsName template='email/external/customer.phtml'}} and $this->mydata; will give me what i want?

Comment: try this will definitely will work

Comment: ok going to try it, did I need to set it in "sendEmail" or not

Comment: This is not working

Comment: @Qaisar Satti..

Comment: can you please provide full code of your email template

Comment: template code is added, please have a look

Comment: there is no `$fieldsName` in your template so how can you pass data. please explain what data you want to pass from where to where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45130/discussion-between-abdul-ghaffar-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Comment: in phtml file if you echo $fieldsName then it will autometically add in the template

Comment: are you there?need your help

Comment: yes tell me ...

Comment: An address attribute is created , let say 'test_price'. This attribute is populated from front end. I have two address, Address one and two, one is on top in admin,if I add some value for 'test_price' for address one from front end.When I go to admin panel, customer address. For one, it is added, but for address two, this is also added, but in DB, there is nothing for address two,

Comment: Any guess that what is happening

Comment: I think you have added some code or some extension may conflict its hard to say something on this

Comment: Ok, and thank you.going to post a query.some one may have faced it

Comment: ok post it some one surely give you answer if they have face the same situation

Comment: are you there?need some help

Comment: hello what help you need ?

Comment: trying to convert quote to order,

Comment: by this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174454/magento-convert-quote-to-order

Comment: facing issues, have you done it some thing like this

Comment: what error you get please describe

Comment: will be back in 10, if you there, will share it

Comment: are you there?, need some help

Comment: above solution will work but I want to pass dynamic vaible..How we will pass the dynamic value?

Comment: @55840 for that you need to pass dynamic variable in email template and need to pass dynamic data, you can check order email for more reference